# I am getting this error while trying to connect to the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

When I attempt to connect to SQL Server, I get the following error:

> Connection to SQL Server failed. Cannot open database "VMWARESERVER"
>   requested by the login. The login failed for user 'sa'.

[Picture of Error for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRfCE.png)

Comment: please describe your problem with more details not only add a image.

Comment: Hello and welcome! To help you, we need more informations. Could you provide us more examples or how you are trying to connect to your database? Looking at your error, which can be write down so its more easy to identify, it seems like your user or password in your connection string is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. First make sure 'sa' user is enabled
2. Change the authentication mode to mixed mode (Window and SQL authentication)
3. Stop your SQL Server
4. Restart your SQL Server. (You can use below steps)
           a. Go to services.msc from run prompt.
           b. Restart the services of SQL server(MSSQLSERVER)
           c. Restart the services of SQL server(SQLEXPRESS)

If you need more details, Please check the below link for further details.

[For additional details please visit below web site](http://itproguru.com/expert/2014/09/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-step-by-step-add-sql-administrator-to-sql-management-studio/)